# Search customer by ID not printing

Tags: java

I dont know why my code is not working at all. In my Eclipse there's no errors shown at all.

I want to use the id to print the name of my customers, and that's my goal

`````
Customer[] custArray = { new Customer("Chen",35), new Customer("You",36) };


public Customer searchCustomerByID(int custID){
               for(Customer c:customers){
                 if(c.getID() == custID)
                   return c;
               }
               return null;
             }
````
`````

Comment: `my code is not working at all` makes this question [off-topic at Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please  heed [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @greybeard: Actually, here we only want a CVE, a Complete and Verifiable Example. We want to have all the code rather than example code taken out of context.

Comment: (@Graipher: as I augmented the explication of mcve with the site I have been referring to, I think the `Actually` is uncalled for.)

Comment: @greybeard: Yes, that first sentence certainly helps. However I think linking to the SO mcve page is not the best way to show the OP how a question should look like on Code Review. IMO the link to our help center should be sufficient. Otherwise you would always have to specify which parts of the mcve page need to be explicitly ignored when posting here (namely the minimal part).

Comment: (As the question is entirely off-topic here, I tried to refer poster and question to SO.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You wrote this:

```java
for (Customer c : customers)
{
    if (c.getID == customID) return c;
}
```

The array is called `custArray`. And the for-each is iterating over an array of `Customer`s cales `customers`. So, the simple solution is to change `customers` to `custArray`! Hope that helps. ;)

EDIT: this should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please refuse to answer off-topic questions.